# Force change State/Status to Complete

Tags: order-status, programmatically, status, order-state, state

Is possible to change the **state** of the **order** to complete?

```
$order->setSate(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```

Programmatically : setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE) will generate Exception.

---

```
$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```

With setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE) => Server Error "404 Not Found - nginx".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The 404 error may not be related, it could be simply bad URL.

Comment: Yep. I thought of that, too. Thanks for feedback.